# Running Quantlib with Visual Studio Code in Mac

Tags: quantlib

I wanted to run `Quantlib` with `Visual Studio Code` in `Mac`. I have successfully installed `Quantlib` in `Mac` as per the instructions in https://www.quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml, which is working with `Xcode`.

However when I tried to run the below dummy code for `Quantlib` I failed to compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <ql/option.hpp>

using namespace QuantLib;
 
int main() {
    
}
```

The error I was getting -

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, char const*, long)", referenced from:
      boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Observable>::operator->() const in Try-731982.o
      boost::unordered::detail::table<boost::unordered::detail::set<std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::Observer*>, QuantLib::Observer*, boost::hash<QuantLib::Observer*>, std::__1::equal_to<QuantLib::Observer*> > >::get_bucket_pointer(unsigned long) const in Try-731982.o
      boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::DayCounter::Impl>::operator->() const in Try-731982.o
      boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Calendar::Impl>::operator->() const in Try-731982.o
      boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::IndexManager>::operator*() const in Try-731982.o
      boost::unordered::detail::functions<boost::hash<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Observable> >, std::__1::equal_to<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Observable> > >::~functions() in Try-731982.o
      boost::unordered::detail::table<boost::unordered::detail::set<std::__1::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Observable> >, boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Observable>, boost::hash<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Observable> >, std::__1::equal_to<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Observable> > > >::get_bucket_pointer(unsigned long) const in Try-731982.o
      ...
  "QuantLib::Observable::notifyObservers()", referenced from:
      QuantLib::InterestRateIndex::update() in Try-731982.o
  "QuantLib::TermStructure::update()", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::TermStructure in Try-731982.o
  "QuantLib::Date::Date()", referenced from:
      QuantLib::TermStructure::timeFromReference(QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
  "QuantLib::Error::Error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, long, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      QuantLib::TermStructure::settlementDays() const in Try-731982.o
      QuantLib::InterestRateIndex::valueDate(QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
      QuantLib::InterestRateIndex::pastFixing(QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
      QuantLib::DayCounter::yearFraction(QuantLib::Date const&, QuantLib::Date const&, QuantLib::Date const&, QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
      QuantLib::Calendar::isBusinessDay(QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
  "QuantLib::Index::addFixing(QuantLib::Date const&, double, bool)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::InterestRateIndex in Try-731982.o
  "QuantLib::Coupon::accept(QuantLib::AcyclicVisitor&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::Coupon in Try-731982.o
  "QuantLib::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, QuantLib::Date const&)", referenced from:
      QuantLib::InterestRateIndex::valueDate(QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
      QuantLib::InterestRateIndex::pastFixing(QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
  "QuantLib::IndexManager::getHistory(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
      QuantLib::Index::timeSeries() const in Try-731982.o
  "QuantLib::TermStructure::referenceDate() const", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::TermStructure in Try-731982.o
  "QuantLib::InterestRateIndex::fixing(QuantLib::Date const&, bool) const", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::InterestRateIndex in Try-731982.o
  "QuantLib::Calendar::advance(QuantLib::Date const&, int, QuantLib::TimeUnit, QuantLib::BusinessDayConvention, bool) const", referenced from:
      QuantLib::InterestRateIndex::valueDate(QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
  "QuantLib::CashFlow::hasOccurred(QuantLib::Date const&, boost::optional<bool>) const", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::Coupon in Try-731982.o
  "typeinfo for QuantLib::Error", referenced from:
      QuantLib::TermStructure::settlementDays() const in Try-731982.o
      QuantLib::InterestRateIndex::valueDate(QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
      QuantLib::InterestRateIndex::pastFixing(QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
      QuantLib::DayCounter::yearFraction(QuantLib::Date const&, QuantLib::Date const&, QuantLib::Date const&, QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
      QuantLib::Calendar::isBusinessDay(QuantLib::Date const&) const in Try-731982.o
  "typeinfo for QuantLib::Index", referenced from:
      typeinfo for QuantLib::InterestRateIndex in Try-731982.o
  "typeinfo for QuantLib::CashFlow", referenced from:
      typeinfo for QuantLib::Coupon in Try-731982.o
  "vtable for QuantLib::Error", referenced from:
      QuantLib::Error::~Error() in Try-731982.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "virtual thunk to QuantLib::TermStructure::update()", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::TermStructure in Try-731982.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 28.615 seconds
```

Any insight how to successfully run `Quantlib C++` codes with `Visual Studio Code in Mac` will be very helpful.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code compiled, but it didn't link.  You need to add `/usr/local/lib/libQuantLib.dylib` to the build (or `.a`, depending on how you compiled QuantLib—check which files you have in `/usr/local/lib`).  I'm not familiar with VS Code, so I can't guide you step by step, but you can probably find instructions on how to add a library to a build.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for pointing out.